# Bluetooth not working properly on ubuntu

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, vaio, sony

When I turn on my bluetooth in ubuntu 12.04 it does not show any options for discovering devices or any bluetooth functions.
What should I do to show these options?[image]

As you can see even though bluetooth is turn on(in status bar) no options are shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the Following command in the terminal..

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 reset
```

It should than turn ON the bluetooth.

If you are using laptop than try to turn it OFF and ON,using hardware switch. Usually done with Fn + Some function key depending on your laptop.

Also If this doesn't work than install Blueman Bluetooth Manager from Ubuntu Software Center.

Enjoy!!

Comment: I donot know how but it's working suddenly

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command (you don't need to be root)

```
hcitool dev
```

If nothing is listed then you don't have your bluetooth adapter configured properly.

You can also

```
sudo lsmod |grep blue
```

If you find it there, then considering installing rfkill, for enabling/disabling wireless devices.

```
sudo apt-get install rfkill
```

If this not helps, follow this guide. It contains all the information you need for setting up your bluetooth adapter.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BluetoothSetup